# How get latest text from messages app on mac to use for Xcode

Tags: xcode, message, imessage

I know this is possible because I've seen somebody do this on another application but I was wondering if anyone knew how to do this.

Thank you

Comment: That device was Jailbreaked.

Comment: My bad I forgot to add that it was on mac so the program would have access to the db or such

Comment: Did you find out more? I'm also curious about a solution.